# In conky, how to have different update interval to monitor USB memory drive only

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, conky

I´ve got a question regarding a specific part of a *conky-config*.

I understand that by setting the **update_interval** parameter to 1.0 the whole conky application updates every second.

What I want to achieve is excluding  a particular part of what conky monitors and assigning another update interval to it.
In other words: overriding the settings of **update_interval** but only for a particular part of conky.

E.g.:

I have a line that looks like this (monitoring my USB-stick 1):

```
${color SlateBlue1}stick1:${fs_used /media/rosika/28BC-DAFC}/${fs_size /media/rosika/28BC-DAFC} used:${fs_used_perc /media/rosika/28BC-DAFC}% ${fs_bar /media/rosika/28BC-DAFC}
```

But as there´s no point in updating the values of that stick every second I´d like it to set to e.g. 2 hours. 
Is that that possible at all?

P.S.:

System: Linux/Lubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, 64 bit

Comment: I have my RAM and four storage locations updated every second in Conky. It's been that way for years and I never worried about it. After reading your question I updated my conky with `fs_bar` and I do like the new look :)

Comment: @all: discussion moved to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81211/discussion-between-rosika-and-ravexina